# Optimize count and select query

Tags: mysql, optimization, count, full-text-search

I am using MySQL 5.5. I have a query (fulltext) which uses a subquery. To help performance and the fact that I am using pagination, I am using LIMIT to limit the number of results.

```
SELECT * 
FROM ( 
    SELECT id, type, type_id, content, MATCH(content) AGAINST('john') as relevance, IFNULL  (parent_type, UUID()) as parent_type, IFNULL(parent_id, UUID()) as parent_id 
    FROM search_index
    WHERE MATCH(content) AGAINST('john*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) GROUP BY parent_type, parent_id ) as search 
GROUP BY search.type, search.type_id DESC LIMIT 10;
```

The thing is, in addition to that, I need to send back the total number of possible results for example (50000) with each search query. To get the count, I am using:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM(
    SELECT * 
    FROM ( 
        SELECT id, type, type_id, content, MATCH(content) AGAINST('john') as relevance, IFNULL  (parent_type, UUID()) as parent_type, IFNULL(parent_id, UUID()) as parent_id 
        FROM search_index
        WHERE MATCH(content) AGAINST('john*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) GROUP BY parent_type, parent_id ) as search 
    GROUP BY search.type, search.type_id) as count;
```

This does makes me somewhat uneasy though. Here's the explain for the count query:

[image]

`search_index` is a fulltext index on `content`.
`search_index_no_ft` is an index on ALL columns except `content` and `id`.
There's a primary key on `id`.

Is there a better way to do this, perhaps a way to optmize this? Or, is there a way to combine the 2 queries (count and search) into 1?

Comment: Do you really need exact number of matches? There must be a reason for google to show only estimates...

Comment: I need the exact number of matches to generate a pagination that works in most cases, for example, when filtering and searching user lists etc. If it was a general site-wide search, I am happy with an estimate as the amount of data is so large that the user would never go through all of it anyway. So yes, I need an exact match for my use case.

Comment: Some users will try to go through all of them anyway if you let them do it, abusing highest offsets in websites with pagination based on limit is a common type of dos attack.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS? It works like this:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS some_fields FROM table WHERE xxx LIMIT 10;
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

The only limit is that you have to execute second query immediately after first one.
More at mysql docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows
Don't know how it will behave with concurent queries, so you will have to check this.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized I made a fatal mistake in my quesiton. I need to return the total number of possible rows for the search and a subset of the rows as set by LIMIT. The effect I want is similiar to search engines: `showing 10 of 10000 possible results` and the first 10 results and so on (depending on which page the user is on).